# Hide AutoExec() and AutoNew() macros from the macro list yet still have them run?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, hide

I'm trying to keep certain macros running when Word fires up or opens another document, but I want them removed from the list of macros the user can access (alt+f8).

I've tried adding 'private' instead of 'public', but this stops them running altogether for some reason.

```
Public Sub AutoExec()
    DisplayStylesMenu
End Sub

Public Sub AutoNew() 
    DisplayStylesMenu
End Sub

Public Sub AutoOpen() 
     DisplayStylesMenu
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayStylesMenu()
    ' Opens the Formatting task pane (Style window)
    Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True

    ' Docks the window on the right
    Application.CommandBars("Styles").Position = msoBarRight
End Sub
```

Currently, AutoExec, AutoNew and AutoOpen all appear in the publicly accessible macros list (because of the 'public' prefix), but when adding 'private' to any of them, they stop working and there's no error.

**How can I keep the macros running on startup, opening a doc etc whilst hiding them from the macro list?**

Comment: Did you try to modify the accessor "Public" to "Private"? It may help.

Comment: I did, and it stops the macros appearsing AND running altogether, which defeats the purpose. I added it to 'AutoExec', 'AutoNew', 'AutoOpen' and 'Sub DisplayStylesMenu', no combination seems to work for me.

Comment: Then you should probably create a template file and put the macros in it, and open new word document based on that template.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I've got set up. The macros live in the Normal.dotm template, on which all new documents are based. Because the macros list shows macros saved in the Normal.dotm file by default as well as the current document, they are present no matter what document the user has open.

I tried this too:

    `Private Sub AutoNew()
        
        MsgBox "test"

        Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True
        Application.CommandBars("Styles").Position = msoBarRight

    End Sub`

This didnt show the msgbox, so how can private subs can run automatically?

Comment: You probably need to create your own template and open new Word docs based on that template.

Comment: That's what I meant by my last comment, the macros live in the Normal.dotm template, the template on which all new documents are based. It behaves just like any other Word template, except that Word can specifically grab resources from it (like marcos) when accessing other documents. Besides, for technical reasons I need to find a way of making this work in the one template.

Answer (score 4):

One way to prevent macros from being shown in the list of macros is to structure them so that they require at least one argument. This can be an essentially a "dummy" variable which will not actually be used.

So, declare a constant in the module, like so:

```
Const hiddenMacro as Boolean = True
```

I used a boolean, but you could use String, Integer, Long, etc.

Then, in your `AutoNew` subroutine, add this variable as a required argument:

```
Sub AutoNew(hiddenMacro as Boolean)
    MsgBox "Hello, world!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Macros which require arguments do not appear in the macro list:

[image: Screenshot of macro list which excludes macros that require arguments]

**Update** Here I highlight what the `ThisDocument` module is, and show clearly where all of this code belongs in the the `ThisDocument` module of the Normal.dot file.

[image: Another screenshot with highlighting and junk]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David, forgive my ignorance, but which part of the markup is the 'module'? I tried pasting it into the various parts of my macro, and it does hide them from the list, but they no longer run. I think the problem may be where I placed the
`Const hiddenMacro as Boolean = True`

Comment: In the code I tested, both the subroutine `AutoNew` and the `Const hiddenMacro as Boolean = True` were placed in the `ThisDocument` module. Let me know if you can't see the screenshot and I can try to get a better/bigger one.

Comment: There's no screenshot :( I don't think they can be added to comments, can they?

Comment: There's a giant screenshot in my answer, above. You should be able to see that in the VBE window, all the code is in the `ThisDocument` code module.

Comment: Are you referring to the code included in your reply above, or an actual image?

Comment: @user1594373 the code is provided in my answer, there is a GIANT SCREENSHOT where you should be able to clearly see the VBE window, and where this code is located (in the `ThisDocument` module of my Normal.dot.  All of the code in my answer belongs in this module.  Do you understand what `ThisDocument` code module is?

Comment: David, sorry but there is no image appearing in your answer. In the page code, your screenshots appear, but they're only 2 x 1px, and obviously aren't displaying correctly for some reason. I've tried it in multiple browsers, same thing. My VBA knowledge is pretty limited, as I only dip into it when a task requires.

Comment: Both, and for some reason the images are now displaying correctly. Weird. Thanks a lot for that, that clears it up :)

Comment: Works perfectly - this is fantastic, but also one of the many reasons I hate VBA and MS Office - nothing is ever straight forwards.